# Process for publishing a google editor addon for certain users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a sheet editor addon that I made for a client.

I'm trying to deploy it just for him and his employees.

If I publish it privately in his domain, how can I give myself access on a normal Gmail domain?

For this case there won't be too many users, I can specify them all as testers if needed, but can't figure out how.

Help is much appreciated good fellows.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish the add on internally, you wan't be able to access it with your free Google account.
What you can do is publish the test add-on and make sure that you have access to the script code.
More details [in the official docs](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons)